# Spring boot admin: Full authentication is required to access this resource

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, microservices, spring-boot-admin

we are using netflix oss for reverse proxying and security of microservices, we are following  the jhipster pattern mentioned here https://www.jhipster.tech/microservices-architecture/, where request from UI application  goes to gateway which is Api Gateway and it proxies the request to our backend microservices , we are using jwt for authentication, we wanted a dashboard to monitor our microservices and api gateway which registers with eureka server , we started a separate spring boot admin server so that it registers with eureka server and poll microservices and gateway for metrics endpoint but we are getting exception

> Full authentication is required to access this resource

which is thrown by filters which are filtering for jwts at both api gateway and microservices level,
we also tried disabled

```
management.security.enabled: false
```

but still no luck ,can some one please help to guide what changes i need to make   to enable spring boot admin to successfully poll  the microservices and api gateway?

I tried the following approach

firstly i enabled  web.ignoring().antMatchers("/actuator/**"), so that actuator endpoints are ignored by spring security but this approach will risk my api's

Second idea:

if i enable 2 filters in spring security , the first filter would be for spring boot admin with basic authentication for actuator endpoints  and second filter will be of my jwt authentication for rest all api's and downstream api's not sure will it be feasible?

i enabled the 2 filters one filter for actuator end points and 1 filter for api's but these filters are working perfectly but not able to connect to SBA

```
public class SpringSecurityAdminFilter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {



@Autowired
public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

       String password = passwordEncoder().encode("xxxx");
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder()).withUser("sam").password(password).roles("ADMIN");

}

@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

  http.csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/actuator/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
    .and().httpBasic()
    .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);//We don't need sessions to be created.
}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i enabled basic authentication for spring boot admin server added the property in microservices

```
eureka.instance.metadata-map.user.name: 
eureka.instance.metadata-map.user.password:
```

now actuator endpoints are protected by basic authentication

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue. On my spring boot application we had a cors filter to block Http Head requests. So head requests cannot be accepted from spring boot admin.

- Check maybe filter is blocking HEAD Http requests .
- Setting management.security.enabled=false in the application.properties also necessary.